# Vuetify js Optimization with Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

We are using Nuxtjs 2.3.4 and VuetifyJS 1.2.10.

There is a lot of unused CSS and js from VuetifyJs on each and every page.

How can I remove unwanted css/js of VuetifyJs from each page??

Can anyone help!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [vuetify loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader) for this

In your nuxt.config.js

```
    import VuetifyLoaderPlugin from 'vuetify-loader/lib/plugin' 
    ...

    build: {
      transpile: ['vuetify/lib'],
      plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],
```

in plugins

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Or you can just use [nuxt-vuetify](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) module with treeshake option

Comment: vuetify loader is with Vuetify version 1.3.0 correct??!! I'm on 1.2.10

Comment: @HardikShah yes, you need at least vuetify 1.3 for this. For 1.2 you cant do anything

Comment: still getting the error of duplicate CSS.
https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-1z4qt